# Would searches from a proxy simulating local country searches be considered legitimate and boost CTR?

Tags: seo, google, search-results, proxy, ctr

I have a website and would like to know if searches from a proxy simulating local country searches would count as legit in the eyes of Google thus boosting the CTR? And would this boost the site's ranking in SERPS?

Answer (score 1):

Whether it will count as legitimate or not is something under Google’s control, however you should avoid such practices as google is a data company and it has multiple data gathering points, for example Google Analytics.

When you will use a proxy address, it is likely that Google will already know where this address has been used previously and on which websites. Like most services Google would have already identified that proxy address as a spam and abusive address and may not consider it as a legitimate user.
Your focus should be on the best practices in SEO. All the best